# How would I check a Discord message for an image?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am currently trying to make a bot for my friend so he can finish making his Discord server, and he wants the bot to be able to add a reaction to a image with Discord.py.
Here is my code to check for the image so far:

````
async def on_message(ctx, message)
    pic_ext = ['.jpg','.png','.jpeg']
    for ext in pic_ext:
    if message.content.endswith(ext):
        ctx.send("Image!")```
````

Comment: You can check for [attachments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments). Have you done that already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dominik states: you should check for attachments. A way I've found of doing so is:

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.attachments) > 0: #Checks if there are attachments
        for file in message.attachments:
            for ext in pic_ext:
                if file.filename.endswith(ext):
                    print(f"This message has an Image called: {file.filename}")
```